# Cocoa Touch: can I add a non-integer tag to a UI element?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there an easy way for me to attach a property to a given UI element without subclassing it.

What I'd like is basically just like .tag but I'd want it to hold an NSString. the .tag only holds an integer.

Thanks

Comment: tag can only be integer.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the approach of adding a Category, possibly something like `extendedTag` which would provide access to an NSString.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functionality of associated objects introduced in the IA64 and ARM Objective-C runtimes. This works on on device for iOS, but not on the simulator since the simulator uses the old fragile 32-bit Objective-C run-time.

Here is a small example that allows you to set any kind of object as a context value on all `UIView` instances. The associated objects are released properly at dealloc, so no extra memory management needed.

```
// UIView+CWObjectContext.h
@interface UIView (CWObjectContext)

@property(nonatomic, retain) id objectContext;

@end


// UIView+CWobjectContext.m
#import "UIView+CWobjectContext.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
@implementation UIView (CWObjectContext)

static void* const objectContextKey = "objectContext";

-(id)objectContext;
{
   return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, 
                                   objectContextKey);
}

-(void)setObjectContext:(id)object;
{
   objc_setAssociatedObject(self, 
                            objectContextKey, 
                            object, 
                            OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Comment: Very slick. The only caveat would be testing in the sim.

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob replied this isn't possible. However, so I don't get mixed up when using tags, I use

```
#define EasyToRememberName 5
```

If I were dynamically trying to apply an NSString in code, I would use an NSDictionary containing the NSStings as keys and use NSNumbers as the tag values. That way I could use

```
[[exampleDictionary objectForKey:@"tag string"] intValue]
```

Comment: Man, you just NSStung me! :-)

Comment: You misspelled NSString to be NSSting! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass when you feel the need for non-integer tags. That will turn out to be a better approach as the time goes on.